Bazel cc_binary uses as deps attr a cc_library comming from another repo however not using it
I am new in Bazel and trying to build a cc_binary with cc_library from another repository. Lets assume we have two repos: repA repB
in repA:
   -uart.c
   -uart.h
   -BUILD

the content of BUILD is the following:
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])
cc_library(
    name = "uart",
    srcs = [
        "uart.c",
    ],
    hdrs = [
        "uart.h",
    ],
)


in repB:
   -hello_world.c
   -hello_world.h
   -main.c
   -BUILD

the content of BUILD is the following:
cc_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = [
        "main.c",
    ],
    deps = [
        ":hello_world",
    ],
)

cc_library(
    name = "hello_world",
    srcs = [
        "hello_world.c",
    ],
    hdrs = [
        "hello_world.h",
    ],
    deps = [
        "//repA:uart",
    ],
)

If try to build hello_world it gives me the following error (the same applies if building main binary):
  /gcc-compiler/bin/riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -MD -MF bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/repB/_objs/hello_world/hello_world.d '-frandom-seed=bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/sw/testlist/Debug/_objs/hello_world/hello_world.o' '-DBAZEL_CURRENT_REPOSITORY=""' -iquote . -iquote bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin '-std=gnu11' -c repB/hello_world.c -o bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/repB/_objs/hello_world/hello_world.o)
# Configuration: 0f8097b1395089db7bf8bb7a71ae2834bd242d8064325600934daade0dbae90f
# Execution platform: @local_config_platform//:host

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox and retain the sandbox build root for debugging
repB/hello_world.c:3:10: fatal error: uart.h: No such file or directory
    3 | #include "uart.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~

However, if i put all files in the same repo, it builds successfully
Seems to me I am missing something very tiny...
Any help would be greatly appreciated

okey, I found out that a simple way to solve the problem is to change from
#include "uart.h"
to
#include "repA/uart.h"
which is not "elegant" in my view, cause the path to header file can be longer...
are there any ways to workaround it in Bazel?

please make sure that your code is displayed different than the answer content
